# How do I change the path of pylint in coc.nvim?

Tags: neovim, coc.nvim

I am using the CoC extension in Neovim. When I import some python modules I have installed, pylint shows an error, as if they were not installed, even though they are. I know this because the file executes correctly (and I installed them previously). After doing `:CocCommand workspace.showOutput Pyright`, I get the path of the version of python being used, and of course it is not the one I want. But I don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. activate the correct Python used in your project, make sure `which python` points to the correct path, launch nvim
2. set the path in `coc-settings.json` by `python.pythonPath`, default is `python` that use from $PATH.